# Is there a way to deep-link the Chrome app?

Tags: javascript, android

I'm trying to deeplink the Chrome app from within other mobile browsers like Facebook and Telegram because I'm facing an issue when trying to show users a Push notification prompt, they can't see it if they are using 3rd party browsers.

I have came across a way to deeplink Youtube but changing `youtube` to `chrome` doesn't seem to help.

Is there a way to have mobile Chrome opened with the URL for mobile users that have Chrome installed?

```
       window.onload = function() {
            var desktopFallback = "https://google.com/",
            mobileFallback = "https://google.com/",
            app = "vnd.chrome://google.com"; // Doesn't work
            if( /Android|iPhone|iPad|iPod/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
                window.location = app;
                window.setTimeout(function() {
                    window.location = mobileFallback;
                }, 25);
            } else {
                window.location = desktopFallback;
            }
            function killPopup() {
                window.removeEventListener('pagehide', killPopup);
            }
            window.addEventListener('pagehide', killPopup);
        };
```

Comment: I'm not sure the word "deeplink" means what you think it means https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_linking

Comment: You're right. What I've meant is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_deep_linking but I guess there's no such tag on SO for mobile deep-linking so ill just remove this tag and add Android instead.